# Show/hide div based on url with php

Tags: php, url, html, uri, hide

I'm currently working on a wordpress site and i'm using the same page-templates on two pages. The page-template file is single.php . Now i've got a history back button that needs to be on one of the pages and not on both. Also i'm using the permalinks. Well since i'm not that good at php i'm going to ask you to help me out. I've already found the following code on the internet but i can't get it to work:

The php:

```
<?php
    if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "localhost:8888/sunbook/reader-comments/") >= 0) {
        $historyback_class = "showme";
    }
    else {
        $historyback_class = "hideme";
    }
?>
```

The html:

```
<div id="historyback" class='<?php echo $historyback_class; ?>'>
    <script>
        function goBack()
        {
            window.history.back()
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
</div>
```

The css:

```
#historyback { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 95%; max-width: 920px; color: #bfbfbf; font-size: 23px; font-family: 'RobotoLight', Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 28px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
.hideme { display: none; }
.showme { display: block; }
```

I think the problem is in the requested uri because everywhere I see they are calling a php file. Which in my case seems impossible because the templates are the same so that itsn't going to work.

Comment: What does it currently behave like? Test which statement is executed, in the PHP `if-else` you have.

Comment: Currently it only executes the if statement.

Comment: What are the 2 URLs on which it is supposed to trigger different behaviour?

Comment: Currently on my local host:
http://localhost:8888/sunbook/reader-comments/

Here the div should not be shown
and the other one is:
http://localhost:8888/sunbook/news/first-review-2/

Comment: add your answer below as an answer, rather than an edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Will, wanted to do that but I wasn't able to do that because of some restrictions. (Just became a user or something, not enough rep points? I don't remember the exact reason.)